# Jsoup missing elements when parsing

Tags: html, jsoup, html-parsing

Consider the below HTML snippet:

```
String content = "<div id='id_1' contenteditable='false' data-hb='true' data-hbtype='ifequal' data-inv='' data-body='ifequal' data-code='{{#ifequal eventInfo.eventType "customer"}}'>
<td style="line-height:18px;" align="left">
<font face="Trebuchet MS, arial, helvetica" size="1" color="#58595b" style="font-size:13px;">
This is just to confirm that we've cancelled your <span id='id_2' contenteditable='false' data-hb='true' data-hbtype='variable' data-inv='' data-body='' data-code='{{clientInfo.clientName}}'>clientInfo.clientName</span> parcel as requested.
</font>
</td>
</div>"
```

Here upon doing `Jsoup.parse(content)` I am getting below HTML content (with pretty print):

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="id_1" contenteditable="false" data-hb="true" data-hbtype="ifequal" data-inv="" data-body="ifequal" data-code="{{#ifequal eventInfo.eventType &quot;customer&quot;}}">  
<font face="Trebuchet MS, arial, helvetica" size="1" color="#58595b" style="font-size:13px;"> This is just to confirm that we've cancelled your <span id="id_2" contenteditable="false" data-hb="true" data-hbtype="variable" data-inv="" data-body="" data-code="{{clientInfo.clientName}}">clientInfo.clientName</span> parcel as requested.</font>  
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

As can be seen, the `<td>` element is gone in the parsed content. Has anyone faced the same, or am I missing something here?

I also tried https://try.jsoup.org/ which is some sort of a playground to try JSoup, but this too gives the same output.

Is there any other HTML parser I should be using here?

Comment: Placing the td there is invalid HTML. td elements must be in a tr element which has to be in a table element. You will either need to fix your html or use a generic xml parser which accepts anything

Comment: @JensV thanks for pointing it out.